# WPF Excel-like Arrow key feature with Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have about 600 text boxes side-by-side (looks like a matrix). Each of the text box is named by row and column number. i.e. 
textbox_12_25 would be textbox in 12th row and 25th column.

Is there way to implement features like Excel using Arrowkeys and Enter?

I am pretty new to C# and WPF, so a detailed and simple answers would be appreciated.

Comment: pioneer, If my answer helped you, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list box and modify the ItemTemplate and ItemsPanel

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ShippingBays}" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="2" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBay}" Background="White" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12" Padding="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}" Rows="{Binding RowCount}" />
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      </ListBox>
```

This is some of the code I wrote for a similar application. Though I do not enter information in the boxes, I just display it. I know this isn't an exact answer but its a way to do it even if you had to modify how you are adding the boxes, etc.

My grid appears with A at the bottom because i'm sorting by RowCount descending, otherwise A would be the top row, just like excel.

[image]